# Missing googleapis/google/protobuf

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-speech

I am attempting to compile a C# library for GoogleCloudSpeechToTextv1p1beta1 from a .proto file [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/cloud/speech/v1p1beta1/cloud_speech.proto). The protobuf compiler works, except that it is missing dependencies from the googleapis/google/protobuf directory. All of the other import files that it depends on exist, [here](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google).

My question is this: Why is the protobuf directory missing from the [googleapis/google directory](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google)? Is it a library that I need to compile/assemble personally? Or is it something Google should be providing and it's just missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `google/protobuf` directory is shipped with the `Google.Protobuf.Tools` package, under `tools` (so there's `tools/google/protobuf/any.proto` for example). Alternatively, the same files are within the [protobuf GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/protobuf) (under `src` - the protos are mixed with the C++ code).

So you should include the `tools` directory as a "root" in the `protoc` call if you need to... but in this particular case, there's already a [NuGet package of Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1/1.0.0-beta01) so I'd suggest you use that instead :) (There are even [docs available](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1/index.html) if you know to extrapolate the URL scheme from other APIs. It's not really advertised as such.)